# URL.Link(routeName, value) returns Null in the case of Controller level Route attribute

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

If I use `Route attribute` with template `[controller]` then no problem it return values.  But if I use my own template, it returns `null` for other actions except currently executing action. Please see below code (I have added comment)

```
//[Route("[controller]")] - If I use this link1,link2 having proper value.
[Route("country/{countryId}/weather")] //- If I use this, only link1 having proper value.
[ApiController]
public class WeatherForecastControllers : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{stateId}", Name = "GetWeather")]
    public IActionResult GetWeather(string stateId)
    {
        var link1 = Url.Link("GetWeather", new { stateId = 1 });
        var link2 = Url.Link("GetAll", null);

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet("getall", Name = "GetAll")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        return Ok(new List<object>());
    }
}
```

***UPDATE:***

So here `var link2 = Url.Link("GetAll", null);` expect to have countryid here.  But in ASP.NET Web API (.Net 4.8), it automatically pick the value from current request. How to have the same behavior here.

Comment: Update your **UPDATE:** to include full controller code that is working, as you say, in the .Net Framework 4.8. You wrote **_//[Route("[controller]")] - If I use this link1,link2 having proper value_**. So why you don't use it? This is correct way to define routing for the listed methods.

Answer (score 1):

You prefixed your controller with [`Route("country/{countryId}/weather")]`. This is means that to access you `GetAll` API you should provide correct route value, because with this controller route attribute the `GetAll()` API must be accessed by `/country/{countryId}/weather/getall` URL:

```cs
var link2 = Url.Link("GetAll", new { countryId = 123 });
```

Or you can change the `GetAll()` route template to `"/getall"`:

```cs
[HttpGet("{stateId}", Name = "GetWeather")]
public IActionResult GetWeather(string stateId)
{
    var link1 = Url.Link("GetWeather", new { stateId = 1 });
    var link2 = Url.Link("GetAll", null);
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("/getall", Name = "GetAll")]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    return Ok(new List<object>());
}
```

Comment: Great!!! Thanks!! I will shortly accept this as answer.

Comment: Do we have any generic way to set the country id.  In .Net Framework (Asp.net API), the country id value has been retained here as itself.

Comment: @PowerStar: Describe your question more precisely. Add the code fragment from the .Net Framework you are referenced, please. How you want the generated URL will looks like?

Comment: If you run the same controller in .Net Framwork there is no need of adding country id in the object while generating link (it automatically pick country id from current request). But .Net core expect to add the country id.

Comment: @PowerStar: And the **"current request"** look like? Like this: _"/country/123/weather/456"_ ? Where `123`  _countryId_ and `456` is _stateId_.

Comment: Yes exactly correct.